# Functions Defined by Integrals of Non-Elementary Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In calculus I, I encountered the function $e^{-x^2}$. The teacher told us that it was impossible to integrate. Curious, I graphed the function on my calculator, together with its integral. The integral appeared to be a perfectly ordinary function. I wondered whether this function's integral had any special properties as a function, apart from being impossible to define in terms of elementary functions.

Now, I have encountered many such impossible to integrate functions. Are there any such functions that have special properties apart from being impossible to integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are more or less ordinary functions. For example, consider the function $$f(x)=e^{x^2}\int_0^x{e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t}$$  Then $$f'(x)=2xe^{x^2}\int_0^x{e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t}+1$$ So $$f'(x)=2xf(x)+1$$ In other words, this functions is a solution to the differential equation $y'-2xy=1$. The function you mentioned also has the remarkable property that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\sqrt \pi$$ Aside from that, there is nothing *remarkable* per se about functions that cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Many power series, for example, have the same property.